# Python - why are 2 completely different strings the same

Tags: python-3.x, string

So, recently I was working on a programming challenge I made for myself and when I was playing around with strings and I managed to come across this.

```py
"/|||||\\" in "//|||||\ "
```

This, for some reason, returned True and I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently in the 2nd one, Python is escaping the backslash as if you typed `"//|||||\\ "`. If I type `"//|||||\ "` in Idle, it prints `'//|||||\\ '`.

Comment: "Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the string. (This behavior is useful when debugging: if an escape sequence is mistyped, the resulting output is more easily recognized as broken.)" https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html